# Does (passive) Cold Blooded apply to enemies if they were frozen by my mirror images and not me?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

Using the Diablo 3 Wizard Spell "Mirror Images" or "Teleport: Fracture", do the created mirror images make use of passive effects?

*theoretical build example:* http://us.battle.net/d3/en/calculator/wizard#QlgkSd!RWeS!YZbZYb

**Cold Blooded** - Do enemies frozen/chilled by my mirror images count as "frozen by me"?

Comment: I feel like all the questions you've asked lately about mirror images and the secondary effects of their casts should be combined...

Answer (score 2):

If "pets" you control apply a chill or frozen status debuff, you get the cold blood passive effect.

I use the word pet here to cover anything under your control: mirror images, shadows from the haunt of vaxo, followers (cold weapon procs), familiars, etc.

Comment: that may have been true for the old cold blood that said you do increased damage to frozen/chilled enemies, but they have changed the wording on the passive. http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/passive/cold-blooded

Comment: Yeah it says "by you" as opposed to other players, but your pets still count as "you" (WDs would be pretty sad if they didn't).

Comment: I think the real question here is if the mirror images count as pets. They do not have a follower icon like the WD pets do.

Comment: I always thought of them as a spell effect which would mean that logically their casts should count as "by me" in the way that cold blood works but still not proc things for me (loh, apoc etc) just like area damage on hit and other secondary effects work. I was hoping to clarify this a bit with the experience from other players.

Comment: are you absolutely sure followers still counts as by you?

Answer (score 0):

Cold blooded works on any frozen/slowed enemy  no matter the source. Another player can apply the slowing/freeze effect and you will still get the damage bonus.

Comment: I find this odd after reading the skill description: "Enemies chilled or frozen by you take 10% more damage from all sources for the duration of the chill or Freeze." - makes me wonder if it's the other way around. As long as I cause the chill/freeze, everybody (inluding me) deals 10% more damage... this brings me back to the original question: Does freeze/chill by my mirror images count as "by me" regarding the skill description of "Cold Blooded"?

Comment: @habmalnefrage I think his point was more of, no matter who casts the skill which inflicts chill/freeze (and has cold blooded), everyone gets the benefits of the debuff.  As such, since your Mirror Images have Cold Blooded, and they inflict chill/freeze, you get the benefit just like if a party member with Cold Blooded inflicted chill/freeze you would get the benefit of the damage bonus.

Comment: Thanks Doc. If my mirror images really have my passives, you are right. In that case I am everybody...